# Is it possible to do pagination on tables which don't have repositories in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Some tables are connected to parent by relationships and i don't need a repository for them since i am not doing any updates or inserts. i want to do pagination when i do a find call on parent is it possible?

Comment: please add more info and relevant codes to the question to make it easier to understand what you are asking

Comment: Do you use Hibernate?

Comment: yes i use hibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using Spring Data:**

You can use [PagedListHolder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/support/PagedListHolder.html)

```
List<Animal> animals = animalsService.getAnimals();
PagedListHolder<Animal> pagedListHolder = new PagedListHolder<>(animals);
pagedListHolder.setPageSize(10);
int numOfPages = pagedListHolder.getPageCount();
```

**Using Hibernate:**

**HQL:**

```
Query query = sess.createQuery("From Animal");
query.setFirstResult(0);
query.setMaxResults(10);
List<Animal> animalList = query.list();
```

**Criteria API:**

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Foo.class);
criteria.setFirstResult(0);
criteria.setMaxResults(10);
List<Foo> firstPage = criteria.list();
```

Comment: lets say that animals is connected to another table insects via one to many. U want to achieve pagination on that table. Is it possible?

Comment: Why not? PagedListHolder takes a list of objects and  manages the pagination.

Comment: i see. let me edit the question to be more clear. The problem with your solution is that it will fetch all and then do paging. The reason i want to avoid this is cause i have lots of entries in sub table and i want the paging to happen when query is  executed and not after since it will be slow and reduce response time

Comment: Hibernate's Query and Criteria API don't fetch all rows.